# Why do I always get 401 when trying to access main folder of web site?

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, iis-7.5

I am trying to set up a web site on Windows Server 2008 using IIS 7.5. I have created a new application pool (`TestAppPool`) and a new web site at `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\test`. I have given the Read/Execute permissions to 'IIS AppPool\TestAppPool' (using `icacls`). Authentication is just NTLM.

When I try to access the site, a login prompt comes and will not let me through.

I have followed through the instructions which I found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437723/iis-apppoolidentity-and-file-system-write-access-permissions but still cannot access the web page.

What do I need to do?

The event log contains the following:

```
Event code: 4008 
Event message: File authorization failed for the request. 
Event time: 07.09.2015 14:18:58 
Event time (UTC): 07.09.2015 12:18:58 
Event ID: bdf78e0b751e41dcae5b391d18555406 
Event sequence: 3 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/3/ROOT-1-130861019381349122 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TEST\ 
    Machine name: SRVC200 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 3552 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: IIS APPPOOL\TestAppPool 

Request information: 
    Request URL: http://mywebsrv:8080/ 
    Request path: / 
    User host address: 172.xx.xx.xx 
    User: DOMAIN\me
    Is authenticated: True 
    Authentication Type: Negotiate 
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\TestAppPool 

Custom event details:
```

Comment: Are you logging-in with the user which was granted access permission to the folder? Also refer to this [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694162/windows-authentication-failing-in-iis-7-5).

Comment: @Minagushi - if I add my windows user to the folder permissions then I am able to access the site. But that cannot be a solution! I gave permission to `Everyone` and that works too but it's against company policy

Comment: I had to [give `Everyone` read access to that folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752000/iis-file-authorization-failed-for-the-request/59731405#59731405).